Why can the private method be called in the self-injection in Spring Boot?
I know CGLIB is used for the proxy in Spring Boot and CGLIB won't override any private methods. However, if you try to use self-injection to call the private methods, it can be invoked without any exceptions.
I'm curious of why it can be invoked without any exceptions. Also, I am wondering why the other autowired objects will be null because I try to test like how self-injection works in pure Java, it won't be null.
public class AClass {
    private String value;

    public AClass(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AClass a = new ProxyClass("test");
        a.print();
    }

    private void print() {
        System.out.println(this.value);
    }
}

public class ProxyClass extends AClass {
    public ProxyClass(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

The output will be "test", not null
If you do that in Spring Boot like as follows:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {
    
    private final TestService testService;
    private final Object otherBean;
    
    public void publicTest(){ // callee = TestService
        otherBean.doSomeThing();
    }
    
    private void privateTest(){ // callee = TestService$$SpringCGLIB and all autowired are null
        otherBean.doSomeThing();
    }
}

when you breakpoint at publicTest(), you will find "this" is TestService.
when you breakpoint at privateTest(), you will find "this" is TestService$$SpringCGLIB but all autowired is null. However, if CGLIB doesn't override private method, why can it call privateTest() without exception?
Answer:
I have drawn a picture to readily understand the reason.


The example code will not compile because AClass has a blank final which is never initialized.   (There won't be ANY output!)  Please fix the code in your question so that we can make sense of what you are trying to ask.

You can call the private method from inside the class, but it won't go through the proxy. So anything in the proxy, like annotations, won't be executed.

@StephenC updated code.

@EssexBoy please see updated question. call the private method from inside the class, you can see "this" is TestService$$Enhancer$$CGLIB proxy

@EssexBoy and if you call publicTest() from outside (autowired), you can see "this" is TestService itself

I closed the question as a duplicate, because if you read this one first to understand why a Spring proxy does not work the way you think it does and then that one to understand why field values in your proxy are null, your question(s) should be answered.

CGLIB proxies don't override private methods and self-injection works through reflection, not proxy inheritance. By calling a private method directly, you force it to bypass Spring's proxy mechanism. So, you might want to access Spring-managed beans through their proxies (self-injected instance) to call methods.
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {
    private final TestService testService;
    private final Object otherBean;
    
    public void publicTest() {
        // This will work correctly with all autowired beans
        testService.protectedTest();
    }
    
    // Change from private to protected
    protected void protectedTest() {
        otherBean.doSomeThing();
    }
}


I know the solution but I want to know the mechanism. As you said that by calling Direct private method you force it to bypass Spring's proxy mechanism, but I observe that when you stop at the breakpoint inside the private method that you will find that the this reference is pointed to the Spring Proxy class. It seems to be contradict with what you said.

it is pointed to the Spring Proxy class but not to the right  superclass, which wasn't initialized by Spring, to be precise The dependencies are null because they're accessed through the uninitialized superclass fields

there is another solution if you want to avoid using protected and its by using  "package-private"

After googled a lot, here is my understanding. Spring will initialize proxy the component class but doesn't inject any autowired components at that time. Then if we call the method, its proxy will invoke the method of its superclass and do dependency injection meanwhile. However, if call the private method via self injection, it will directly call the method of superclass and the dependency injection will not be executed so all autowired components will be null. Is this understanding correct?

Yes you are right , so the short answer is : calling private methods or self-invoking methods directly bypasses the proxy and can lead to issues if relying on Spring AOP features.

"CGLIB proxies don't override private methods". Of course not, but this is not CGLIB- or Spring-specific, but simply a fact of the JVM. Private methods are invisible to other classes, even to subclasses (hence also to proxies). Therefore, they cannot be overridden simply due to their visibility constraints.

@Mohamedaminebenhassen I've drawn a picture to explain the reason on the question. Please see whether it is correct. :)

@kriegaex thanks for your nice answer. can u help check the picture I've drawn on the question to see whether my understanding is correct. Thanks. :)

Actually, to me neither your sample code nor your diagram are very helpful. For example, your TestService does not even call its own private method anywhere, i.e. it does not illustrate what the diagram is trying to explain. In the diagram itself, the explanations for the private method are also confusing to me. Maybe, you better follow the links to the two answers I posted in the comment under your question to understand the situation better.
